# How to get workspace location in Eclipse 4.x

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I need to get workspace a location using API in Eclipse 4.x platform. I know that I can use

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();
```

but I'm wondering if there is another way to do that without static reference to `ResourcesPlugin`? For example using Dependency Injection..

Thanks in advance
Qinto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection):

`@Inject
@Named(E4Workbench.INSTANCE_LOCATION)
private Location instanceLocation;`

This didn't work for me in my LifeCycleManager, though, throwing an exception that the Location object was not available to be injected.  I removed the @Named annotation and a valid Location object was injected:

`@Inject
private Location instanceLocation;`

Comment: I can confirm that E4Workbench.INSTANCE_LOCATION does not work in Luna SR1. Unfortunately, in the second approach, the user directory is injected, not the workspace.

Comment: The first approach works in Eclipse Mars, but E4Workbench is not API yet.